# Set environment variable for php

Tags: php, cmd, environment-variables

I installed wamp server. Now I want to execute php script using cmd.

I set the following path in environment variable.

```
Path -> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16
```

Now when I write

```
php -f c:\wamp\www\test\test.php
```

in cmd its giving

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file
```

Comment: Isn't the PHP's binary inside an additional `bin` folder?

Comment: Not really a programming question. I think you'd better ask it at serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

What you have given is correct

```
Path -> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16
```

Can you please close your command prompt, reopen and try it again. The update will reflect now.